# Google Cloud Run error: globalThis is not defined

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-run

I have an Angular app hosted in firebase. I'm uploading it to Google Cloud Run. The container is being created but once the service is run I received error: Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable.

The log gives the error: globalThis is not defined.

I installed globathis with npm and added it to polyfills.ts as first import as below. I also tried with ungap global this. After this I created the container again and refreshed the service, but I receive same error

```
import '@ungap/global-this';
import 'globalthis/auto';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

This is what I get in the log:

```
ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined
    at Module.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/dist/topicos/server/main.js:168651:1)
    at Module.jmUF (/usr/src/app/dist/topicos/server/main.js:168726:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (/usr/src/app/dist/topicos/server/main.js:26:30)
    at Object.ZAI4 (/usr/src/app/dist/topicos/server/main.js:134936:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (/usr/src/app/dist/topicos/server/main.js:26:30)
    at Object.24aS (/usr/src/app/dist/topicos/server/main.js:42119:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (/usr/src/app/dist/topicos/server/main.js:26:30)
    at Object.K011 (/usr/src/app/dist/topicos/server/main.js:98994:27)
    at __webpack_require__ (/usr/src/app/dist/topicos/server/main.js:26:30)
    at Object.uj+Y (/usr/src/app/dist/topicos/server/main.js:188144:23)
```

Below the angular and package version as reference:

```
Angular CLI: 11.0.7
Node: 14.17.3
OS: darwin x64

@angular-devkit/architect       0.1100.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1100.7
@angular-devkit/core            11.0.7
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.0.7
@angular/cdk                    11.2.13
@angular/cli                    11.0.7
@angular/fire                   6.1.5
@angular/material               11.2.13
@nguniversal/builders           11.2.1
@nguniversal/express-engine     11.0.1
@schematics/angular             11.0.7
@schematics/update              0.1100.7
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.0.8
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. I assume (!?) when you deploy to Firebase the app is working correctly? You must containerize the app before you can deploy it to Cloud Run. Before you deploy the containerized app to Cloud Run, can you run it locally? I suspect the problem is in containerizing the app and that it won't run locally either. One advantage with containers is that they should run anywhere and you can leverage this fact in testing.

Comment: What your dockerfile? What your packages.json file?

Comment: Well I hadn´t tested it locally as was just following some example that made it directly to GCP. Once I run it locally I found some things in the Dockerfile to update like the node version and the directory. Now it deployed to the service in GCP.

Comment: Could you please share what you did to solve your issue? Thank you :)

Comment: I made some changes and I'm not certain of what solved it. Check your Docker file and the node version that you are stating there. I'm using FROM node:14, and that's the same in my package.json. First check that your app is working when you run build:ssr and serve:ssr, then create the docker image and also test it in server.